# How to save Visual Studio project extension properties in a tiered way

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, msbuild, vsix

How would I dynamically create/modify/remove extension properties in a Visual Studio 2015 project file, such that the XML maintains the following construct:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
        <MyProject>
            <MyProjectProperty1>3</MyProjectProperty>
            <MyProjectProperty2>8</MyProjectProperty>
            <MyProjectProperty3>2016</MyProjectProperty>
        </MyProject>
    </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

I already know how to create a variant of that using the EnvDTE.Globals and then persisting the value and optionally saving the project using code similar to:

```
EnvDTE.Project oProject = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
Globals oGlobals = oProject.Globals;
oGlobals["MyProjectProperty1"] = "3";
```

The problem here is that this code yields:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <UserProperties MyProjectProperties1="3" MyProjectProperties2="8" MyProjectProperties3="2016" />
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

I thought of using `IPersistXMLFragment` and `IVsProjectFlavorCfg` combinations, but this approach lacks the key concept of reading, writing, and removing the XML code from the project file. The `IPersistXMLFragment` load method takes XML code as a string, loads the values into a dictionary, and then manages the values. The save method does the reverse going from a management construct back to a string based version of XML. Missing, as I just said, is the read, write, and remove from the actual project file without manually editing the file and causing a project reload.

I was also playing with the `IVsHierarchy` and `MSBuild` VSIX interface/object, but did not get very far.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [IVsBuildPropertyStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage?view=visualstudiosdk-2019). As input I use a [EnvDTE.Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) object.
`SetCsprojProperty` will set the property in the first `<PropertyGroup>` of the csproj file if it does not exist:

```
private IVsHierarchy GetIVsHierarchyObject(Project project)
{
  string uniqueName = project?.UniqueName;
  int ret = Solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(uniqueName, out IVsHierarchy hierarchyProject);
  if (ret != VSConstants.S_OK) return null;

  return hierarchyProject;
}

public string GetCsprojProperty(Project project, string name)
{
  IVsHierarchy hierarchyProject = GetIVsHierarchyObject(project);
  if (hierarchyProject is IVsBuildPropertyStorage buildPropertyStorage)
  {
    var result = buildPropertyStorage.GetPropertyValue(name, "", (uint)_PersistStorageType.PST_PROJECT_FILE, out string value);
    if (result == VSConstants.S_OK)
    {
      return value;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

public bool SetCsprojProperty(Project project, string name, string value)
{
  IVsHierarchy hierarchyProject = GetIVsHierarchyObject(project);
  if (hierarchyProject is IVsBuildPropertyStorage buildPropertyStorage)
  {
    var result = buildPropertyStorage.SetPropertyValue(name, "", (uint)_PersistStorageType.PST_PROJECT_FILE, value);
    if (result == VSConstants.S_OK)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```